# SCP: route from one box to another via box with permissions to both.

Tags: ssh, scp

Suppose I have a terminal where I have access to box A and box B, and I need to copy content from box A to box B.

However, it is considered bad form for me to give log-in permissions to my user in box A to box B.

So, I need to run the following commands:

```
scp boxA:etc . 
scp etc boxB:.
rm etc
```

from my box with both permissions.

Is there a way, using scp, for me to bypass this intermediate write and just transmit through my root terminal from boxA to boxB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-3` [flag](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/scp.1.html):

```
     -3      Copies between two remote hosts are transferred through the
             local host.  Without this option the data is copied directly
             between the two remote hosts.  Note that this option disables
             the progress meter.
```